# Install python package man pages with pip

Tags: python, linux, pip, manpage

I maintain a custom-compiled Python installation in `/opt/python-2.7.6`. I expect man pages to be installed in `share/man`. I have installed several libraries already using `pip` (`numpy`, `scipy`, `matplotlib`, `sympy`). I'm not sure if they *should* come with man pages.

Now, I installed `pygments`. It comes with a binary called `pygmentize`, which is correctly installed in `bin`.

**Sidetracking:** I looked up the files in the Debian package `python-pygments` and it comes with a man page:

```
$ apt-file list python-pygments
...
/usr/share/man/man1/pygmentize.1.gz
...
```

**Back to main topic**: I do not want to install `python-pygments` with `apt-get` because it will be associated with the system Python. I want to keep using `pip` to maintain my custom Python installation. It should be easy to add the `share/man` directory to the `MANPATH` environment variable using `.bashrc`

```
export MANPATH=/opt/python-2.7.6/share/man:$MANPATH
```

**Question:** How do I use `pip` to install man pages together with the Python library?

Comment: I don't think the `pygmentize(1)` manpage actually comes with the source package; Debian adds manpages to a lot of commands in their `.deb` packages.

Comment: @larsmans, do you think this is something I should bring up with the Python community, that man pages be included with `pip`-installed libraries?

Comment: There's usually not a lot of man pages with Python libraries, only occasionally do you find someone has actually included a man page for a script. Most Python documentation is found in the code itself, accessible through the shell CLI command 'pydoc' (inside the Python interpreter itself you can use help(obj|module) to get the same basic documentation. Some packages have advanced documentation using Sphinx (I think scipy, numpy and matplotlib all do, thats how their webpage documentations are generated)

Answer (score 7):

The package does not have a man page, [see here](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/7941677dc77d4f2bf0bbd6140ade85a9454b8b80/setup.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default). It's the [Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#manual-pages) that requires that each program adds a man page. Hence, the package installs one for you.

#### As a side note

If you maintain your own package, you can use the directive `data_files` in your `setup.py`:

```py
setup(
    ...
    data_files = [('man/man1', ['path/to/your/manpage.1/'])],
)
```

If you would like to create a man page automatically for your program (if you are using argparse, take a look at my package [man-utils](https://github.com/oz123/man-utils).

Comment: Maybe also point to e.g. https://linux.die.net/man/1/pygmentize which documents that the man page was created specifically for Debian in the *Author* section.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can no longer pack a package with it. It does not find the file although it is obviously there and stored in the right place. Do you know what I can change ?     
error: can't copy 'nuseradd.1': doesn't exist or not a regular file

Comment: Can you please open an issue in the upstream repository with a full stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for the option *data_files*. I would upvote that, but after @synthesizerpatel comment under the question, I think that manual pages should not be distributed with Python packages, because pip has no general way to install them. Another point is that it's always better to install with a system package (not pip), if that is available. So prepare a dedicated package for each system! That would be cleanest, I think.

Comment: If you want to install the man page from the source directory, instead of `pip install -e .`, use `pip install .`  in the root of the source.